# Extracting a multiline regex without leading tabs

Tags: find, awk

I've been trying to hack a little code extraction script together, but I can't get it to work.

My goal is to examine all .txt files in a directory.  If it contains a line which doesn't start with a tab and includes cat.*.c, then extract lines from there (exclusive) to the last line which starts with } (inclusive) and save it to a file with the same names as the source except for with a .c extension.

My first stab at trying to find it was this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk '/[^ \t]cat .*.c/,/[^ \t]}/'
```

I'm not sure why, but the tab matching doesn't work.

Obviously I would need to do a bit more.  I'll need to loop through the files from `find` and grab the file directory & name...

```
filename=$(basename "$1")
filename="${filename%.*}"
dirname=`dirname "$1"
```

Firstly, though, I need to figure out how to get the text I want.  Is `awk` an appropriate tool for the job?  Would `sed`/`grep` be a better choice?

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

P.S.  I've tried searching around, but the tab issue seems to be unique to me.  And lopsided matching (ex/inclusive) seems to be infrequently used also...

Comment: Note that your awk patterns require some text (which isn't whitespace) before the `cat` and the `}`. Is that intended? If not, you could try using `/(^|[^ \t])cat .*\.c/,/(^|[^ \t])\}/` instead. (The `\}` just to be explicit that this isn't an unmatched regex brace. Bare `}` also does work there.)

Comment: About which tool to use: for multiline pattern matching, you do want to use awk or sed. The filename/directory parsing you mention wanting to do make awk sound like the best choice. You could handle that inside an awk action-block that's more complex than the (implicit) `{ print $0 }` block you're using here.

Comment: are you running linux and do you have pcregrep available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
awk '
  NR==1, !/^[ \t]/ && /cat.*\.c/ {next}
  {a = a $0 "\n"}
  /^\}/ {printf "%s", a; a=""}'
```

And to integrate with find:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec awk '
  FNR == 1 {
    if (newfile != "") close(newfile)
    newfile = FILENAME
    sub(/\.txt$/, ".c", newfile)
    a = ""
  }
  FNR==1, !/^[ \t]/ && /cat.*\.c/ {next}
  {a = a $0 "\n"}
  /^\}/ {printf "%s", a > newfile; a = ""}' {} +
```

Comment: If the input contains any blocks terminated by "}" but *not* starting with a matching "...cat" line (and after a genuine "...cat...}" block), this script will wrongly print them out. Whether it's worthwhile to complicate the script to accommodate that, or just leave it be, I guess depends on what the input is like.

Comment: @dubiousjim, that's what I understood the requirement to be ("up to the last line starting with }"). Otherwise, the script would be a lot simpler and would need to store lines.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had some time to play with sch's answer.  Here's my "final" script, just in case someone else finds it useful:

```
for i in `find . -name '*.txt' -type f`
do
    awk '
FNR == 1 {
    if (newfile != "") close(newfile)
    newfile = FILENAME
    sub(/\.txt$/, ".c", newfile)
    a = ""
}
FNR==1, !/^[ \t]/ && /cat.*\.c/ {next}
{a = a $0 "\n"}
/^\}/ {printf "%s", a > newfile; a = ""}' $i

    filename=$(basename "$i")
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    dirname=`dirname "$i"`
    cfilename="${dirname}/${filename}.c"
    if [ -f ${cfilename} ]
    then
        echo "Extracted code from: ${dirname}/${filename}.txt"
        gccErrors=`gcc -Wall ${cfilename} -o "${dirname}/${filename}" -lm 2>&1`
        if [ -n "${gccErrors}" ]
        then
            echo ${gccErrors}
            gccErrorFile="${dirname}/${filename}_GCCERRORS.txt"
            if [ -f ${gccErrorFile} ]
            then
                echo "Can't write to \"${gccErrorFile}\" File already exists!"
            else
                echo ${gccErrors} > ${gccErrorFile}
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```